# Is rescinding an ITIN mandatory after receiving an SSN?

Tags: taxes, h1-visa

I was in the USA on an H4 visa and then switched to H1B after a while. I filed my tax returns using an ITIN but now that I have received an SSN, should I rescind the ITIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get an SSN, you must use that number for tax purposes from then on, so your ITIN cannot be used anymore. IRS recommends that you inform the IRS once you get an SSN so they can combine all your records under the same number.

https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Additional-ITIN-Information

> **What do I do when I am assigned a social security number (SSN)?**
>
> Once you receive a SSN, you must use that number for tax purposes and
>   discontinue using your ITIN.  It is improper to use both the ITIN and
>   the SSN assigned to the same person to file tax returns.  It is your
>   responsibility to notify the IRS so we can combine all of your tax
>   records under one identification number.  If you do not notify the IRS
>   when you are assigned a SSN, you may not receive credit for all wages
>   paid and taxes withheld which could reduce the amount of any refund
>   due.  You can visit a local IRS office or write a letter explaining
>   that you have now been assigned a SSN and want your tax records
>   combined.  Include your complete name, mailing address, and ITIN along
>   with a copy of your social security card and a copy of the CP 565,
>   Notice of ITIN Assignment, if available.  The IRS will void the ITIN
>   and associate all prior tax information filed under the ITIN with the
>   SSN.  Send your letter to:
>
> ```
>  Internal Revenue Service 
>  Austin, TX 73301-0057
> ```